# How to Clear Value in people picker in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, people-picker

I have list in SharePoint Online. With type control people picker. How to delete the value that has been inputted, when approver 1 edit item to return empty. Thanks

[image]

Comment: How to clear value means ?? Just click on that close icon besides name and value will get cleared in the textbox. According to whatever I am observing in the image that field "Assign To" is a mandatory field so it cannot remain empty, if you try to save it as a blank field in your form.

Comment: I am mean, I am have 3 approver. When approver 1 edit item, put Assign To with field mandatory. then Save Item. And to do Approved in approvals process. When approver 2 edit item on the same item, I am want Assign To previous erased automatic and there is no assign to the input by approver 1

Answer (score 1):

Tested script in my online environment, insert script editor webpart into the edit form and insert below script into it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function () {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var controlName = 'Assigned To';
                // Get the people picker object from the page.
                var peoplePickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");
                //var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']");
                var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];
                if (peoplePicker) {
                    peoplePicker.DeleteProcessedUser();
                }
            }, 500);

        });        
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks guy.. this is work for me!

Comment: You could accept it as answer so it would help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it using JS after loading "clienttemplates.js":

```
var peoplePicketEditor = $('[id^="' + fieldName + '"][id$="ClientPeoplePicker"]');
var spPeoplePicket = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePicketEditor[0].id];
spPeoplePicket.DeleteProcessedUser();
```

to delay execution use:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(youFunction, 'clienttemplates.js');
```

Comment: Hi, does this use tags <script> ?

Comment: You can add JS using [CSR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-jslink-to-spfx-extensions).

Comment: yes, i am add JS using CSr, but not working

Comment: please review my code below:


<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
 var peoplePicketEditor = $('[id^="' + Assign To + '"][id$="ClientPeoplePicker"]');
 var spPeoplePicket = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePicketEditor[0].id];
 spPeoplePicket.DeleteProcessedUser();
 
});
</script>

Comment: You code execute after page loading, you need to attach to change event: when approver change something. Isn't it? What error shows in console log? click F12 to show dev mode.

Comment: yea, i am execute code in "default edit form" in SharePoint list on js link. Right?

Comment: error log: The resource from [sitename] was blocked due to MIME type (“”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Comment: Check file path, fix this error)